# Vue.js Passing variable from Parent to child component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-props

Parent component: `ShowComment`

Child component: `EditComment`

I'm trying to pass the value of `this.CommentRecID` to the child component.

I wrote this in the template of `ShowComment`:

```
<EditComment CommentRecID="this.CommentRecID" v-if="showEdit"></EditComment>
```

and

```
this.showEdit = true;
```

but the value of `this.CommentRecID` is shown as undefined in the child component:

[image]

I thought that writing `props: ["CommentRecID"],` in the child component would have already been enough to pass the data, but it wasn't (because it's related to jQuery I think).

What is wrong with the way I try to pass the values?

Here's the [parent component](https://pastebin.com/6nGtbBT3).

Here's the [child component](https://pastebin.com/Ka7699g7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `this` in VueJS directives. Also, instead of using a static attribute, you need to use `v-bind`:

```
<EditComment v-bind:comment-rec-id="commentRecId" v-if="showEdit"></EditComment>
```

Also, there's an issue with the casing: [for VueJS, in template props should be kebab-cased, while in the component JS logic you should use camelCase props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case). Remember to update your child component's `prop` declaration so that it can read the new prop correctly:

```
 props: ["commentRecId"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made the changes you suggested, but somehow I still get an undefined value for `CommentRecID`. Do you know what the cause might be?

Comment: Looks like your parent element is also receiving it as a prop. Go up the dependency chain until you find the source of `CommentRecId`, and rename all instances of it in JS to camelCase, and all template references to kebab-case. In general though, you should never use PascalCase for your variables unless it's a class.

Comment: @PoliticsStudent No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use VueJS binding

```html
<EditComment :comment-rec-id="CommentRecID" v-if="showEdit"></EditComment>
```

```js
props: ['commentRecId']
```